# Question about holomorphic functions and zero's in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, roots, analytic-functions

The question: Write an example of a connected, open set $U ⊂ C$ and an analytic function $f : U → C$ such
that $f(z)$ has $N$ zeros on $U$ while $f′(z)$ never vanishes on $U$

My guess is that I was going to write a function something like this:

$f(z) = (z-z_1)(z-z_2)*...*(z-z_N)exp(\frac{z}{z_1} + z/z_2 + ... + z/z_N )$ However I think the derivative would not vanish. Am I on the right track with this example. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why $f'(z)$ would never be $0$, for your function $f$.

On the other hand, you can take $g(z)=e^z-1$, with $U$ open, connected and such that $0,2\pi i,4\pi i,\ldots,2(N-1)\pi i\in U$.

Comment: don't you mean $f(z) = e^z-1$?

Comment: Since there was already another function $f$, I decided to use another letter.

Comment: I was just confused, since if you're not going to use $f$, as in the OP's question, what is the point of introducing a new letter (that you don't mention again)?

Comment: It's just that I had already mention the OP's function $f$ and therefore I thought that calling my function $f$ too might be seen as ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Take whatever analytic function $f$ you want, as long as it has at least $N$ zeros which are not zeros of $f'$, and you can choose your $U$ to include those $N$ zeros of $f$ and no zeros of $f'$.  Your function would work fine, except that it's going to be hard to find the zeros of $f'$ explicitly. Somewhat simpler would be 
$$f(z) = (z-1) \ldots (z - N)$$
where  we know all the zeros of $f'$ are real.  Then let $U$ consist of, say, the open upper half plane together with some small open disks around $1, \ldots, N$, small enough to not contain any zeros of $f'$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=z^N-1$ and take $U$ as the open annulus of large radius $2$ and small radius $1/2$:

[image]